# blank rows added in excel sheet when adding data row by by in csv format

Tags: python-3.x, export-to-csv

I am inserting data in a new excel/csv file row by row, but when I open the excel sheet, there is a blank row after every data row. Can Any one help me that what's the problem with code?
!

```
def write_into_csv(row_list,destination_path):
    with open(destination_path, mode='w') as employee_file:
                    employee_writer = csv.writer(employee_file)
                    for row_1 in row_list:
                        print( "row1 ", row_1)
                        employee_writer.writerow(row_1)
 return
```

and this code gives this output with excel:

[image]

Comment: what is the value of row_list?

Comment: its a list of lists, where each inner list is collection of elements like 'begin Time', 'End Time',' Duration', 'Speaker' and 'Text'

Comment: you can say arrow_list is like:                                                                            row_list=[['begin Time', 'End Time',' Duration', 'Speaker' , 'Text' ],                        ['00:00:00','00:05:02', ' ', '{Pause}'],                                                        ['00:05:02', '00:09:3', 00:04:01','Ms. Patte','{Interview Information}'']   ]               and many more elements as internal list of strings